# rspec with Excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xls

I have in my project roo gem and use `Roo::Excel.new(path)`. Now I want to write a spec test for the method where an `.xls` file is uploaded.

I try to create a file:

```
@file_xls = [fixture_file_upload('/files/example.xls', 'application/vnd.ms-excel')]
```

This works well.

```
post :method, :files => @file_xls
```

This don't work. I get this error:

> "/var/folders/wG/wG0fTE+uEMGRa8nEqor1tU+++TI/-Tmp-/file_xls.xls20130527-497-nsnxs is not an Excel file", on line "Roo::Excel.new(path)".

Why?

Comment: I have a feeling that it looks at the file name extension after dot, and thinks that it is not an excel file even not trying to open it

Comment: If I use this file in form from frontend all works well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old topic, but I've just encountered the same issue. I guess the problem is `fixture_file_upload` creates an instance of `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` by the end and it is a bit different than `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, which is created when you use the app in development or production.

Anyway, in my case the problem goes away if I use it this way: `Roo::Spreadsheet.open file.path, extension: :xlsx` instead of: `Roo::Excelx.new file.path`.

It is true to for simple .xls as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Péter Tóth - Toma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3941583/p%C3%A9ter-t%C3%B3th-toma)'s answer.

However, since I have multiple formats I want to accept, I wrote this into my code:

```html
  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when ".csv" then open_format(file, ".csv")
      when ".xls" then open_format(file, ".xls")
      when ".xlsx" then open_format(file, ".xlsx")
      else raise "Unknown file type: #{file}"
    end
  end

  private

  def self.open_format(file, extension)
    Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: extension)
  end
```

I am sure you could make it more "meta" - but this code is explicit about what formats I am accepting.

Hope this helps someone.

RSpec tests pass with this code.